# cross products in complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

What is cross product for complex vector in $\Bbb C^n$ ?
and how to prove if $u,v$ are complex: $|u\cdot v| = |u||v|$ if and only if $u= av$?
do I need here to define the cross product?

Comment: Why do you want to the cross product in $\mathbb C^n$ when there isn't really a geometric interpretation for it?  Is the $*$ here supposed to be the cross product or is it the dot product?

Answer (score 3):

The cross product in $\mathbb{C}^n$... does not exist! See this question: [Why is cross product only defined in 3 and 7 dimensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706011/why-is-cross-product-only-defined-in-3-and-7-dimensions)

Note $\mathbb{C}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ as vector spaces, so can never have a cross product.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that some properties of the cross product cannot be maintained in $\mathbb{C}^3$.  But surely some of them can.  For instance, treated as an algebraic formula, we can maintain most if not all of the algebraic properties: antisymmetry, distributive property, and self annihilation.

Algebraic Definition:
$$\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}=\langle a_2b_3-a_3b_2,\,a_3b_1-a_1b_3,\,a_1b_2-a_2b_1\rangle$$

Antisymmetry:
$$\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{a}=\langle b_2a_3-b_3a_2,\,b_3a_1-b_1a_3,\,b_1a_2-b_2a_1\rangle=-(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})$$

Distributive:
$$\mathbf{a}\times(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c})=\langle a_2(b_3+c_3)-a_3(b_2+c_2),\,a_3(b_1+c_1)-a_1(b_3+c_3),\,a_1(b_2+c_2)-a_2(b_1+b_1)\rangle$$
Then use the distributive property of complex numbers and the definition of addition of complex vectors to write this as $(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})+(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{c})$

Self-Annihilation: This is from antisymmetry, $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{a}=-(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{a})$

Magnitude, taken from the usual inner product does not maintain its meaning.  Specifically, unless $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})\ne0$ in general.  Moreover, the property in question $|\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}|=|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|$ if and only if $\mathbf{u}=a\mathbf{v}$ is clearly false because $(a\mathbf{v})\times\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.

I came across this inquiry because I was wanting to say something about the cross product of real and imaginary parts of a complex eigenvector, but to use the properties of the eigenvector, I wanted to represent and manipulate the real and imaginary parts as linear combinations of complex vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Complex numbers have a well-defined cross product.

The complex cross product is commonly used in physics to compute torques (force $\times$ lever arm), and also the intensity of fields in electricity and magnetism (remember the right-hand rule?).

Given complex numbers a and b, where v,w,x,y are real numbers and i is the imaginary number:

$a = v + wi$ and $b = x + yi$,

the cross product $z = a \times b$ is defined as:

$z = vy - wx$

Note the disappearance of $i$ in the above formula.

The result, $z$, will be a vector along an axis orthogonal to the plane that $a$ and $b$ both lie in, and thus it will not be a member of the complex numbers. You may frequently see $z$ treated as a real number (e.g. "twelve" foot-pounds), even though it technically isn't.

Alternatively, this is the definition commonly used in physics:

$z = |a||b|sin(\theta)$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two complex numbers.

Source:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Vector_Cross_Product#Complex_Numbers

Comment: I think the original question was more directed at vectors in spaces such as $\mathbb{C}^2$, $\mathbb{C}^3$, $\mathbb{C}^4$, et al.